# How to detect the prefix number to show the different color in the js tree?

Tags: php, css, jstree

I am using PHP to create the js tree to display the folder and sub folder name like the below output:

[image: Output]

My problem is how to write the logic code to detect the prefix number to show the different color in the js tree folder and subfolder name?

I want the prefix number follow below the number of range:

```html
Prefix number |      Color 
--------------------------
100 until 199 |      Blue
200 until 299 |      Red
300 until 399 |      Yellow
400 until 499 |      Purple
500 until 599 |      Green
```

Below is my code：

```html
 <?php 
   $folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM folder_category where status=1");

   $folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'],
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
      );
   }

   ?>

   <!-- Initialize jsTree -->
   <div  id="folder_jstree" title="JTM"></div>
   <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
   <textarea style="display:none;" id='txt_folderjsondata'><?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?></textarea>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

   $('#folder_jstree').jstree({ 'core' : {
      'data' : folder_jsondata,
      'multiple': false
   } });

});

  $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  } );

</script>
```

Actually I want the output same like below the sample picture, below the sample picture is not using coding to make it, just I am used the paint software to edit and make it easy to let yours understand what I want to get the output:

[image: Output3]

The result of json_encode($folders_arr) in the below:

```html
[{"id":"1","parent":"#","text":"100 Pentadbiran","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"2","parent":"#","text":"200 Pengurusan Tanah & Bangunan","state":{"selected":true,"opened":true}},{"id":"3","parent":"#","text":"300 Pengurusan Aset","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"4","parent":"#","text":"400 Pengurusan Kewangan","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"5","parent":"#","text":"500 Pengurusan Sumber Manusia","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"6","parent":"1","text":"100-1 Perundangan","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"7","parent":"1","text":"100-2 Perhubungan Awam","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"8","parent":"6","text":"100-1-1 Penggubalan-Penyediaan-Pindaan Undang-Undang-Peraturan","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"9","parent":"6","text":"100-1-2 Khidmat Nasihat","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"10","parent":"8","text":"100-1-1-1 Undang-Undang Kecil Kerja Di Jalan 1996","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"11","parent":"8","text":"100-1-1-2 Undang-Undang Kecil Peruntukan Mengenai Lesen Bersesama (Majlis Perbandaran)","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"12","parent":"8","text":"100-1-1-3 Undang-Undang Kecil Mengkompaun Kesalahan-Kesalahan (Majlis Perbandaran Klang), Jalan Parit dan","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"13","parent":"9","text":"100-1-2-1 Jabatan Penguatkuasaan","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"14","parent":"9","text":"100-1-2-2 Jabatan Bangunan","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"15","parent":"7","text":"100-2-1 Publisiti, Promosi Dan Protokol","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"16","parent":"15","text":"100-2-1-1 Publisiti Dan Kenyataan Media","state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}}]
```

Hope someone can guide me or give me some ideas to make it work. Thanks.

My code here:https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/n6deaocv/1/

Comment: try to provide a link to working code of your issue on somewhere like jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Banzay Because jsdiddle.net cannot link to database. Sorry.

Comment: after `<?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?>` you've got the structure ready to process by jstree , so just put it here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/n6deaocv/1/  I have tried put here the code. Thanks for your helping.@Banzay

Comment: Ok. Could you add to question a result of `json_encode($folders_arr)`?

Comment: @Banzay Added in the question. Hope you can save my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as a standard configuration with jsTree. You could however set li attributes on a node and redraw it. This will update the DOM with the attribute. I'm not sure if this is the best approach to go about it, but it works.

```
$('#folder_jstree').jstree({ 'core' : {
      'data' : folder_jsondata,
      'multiple': false
} });

var getColor = function (i) {
    if (i >= 100 && i <= 199) { return "blue"; }
    else if (i >= 200 && i <= 299) { return "red"; }
    else if (i >= 300 && i <= 399) { return "yellow"; }
    else if (i >= 400 && i <= 499) { return "purple"; }
    else if (i >= 500 && i <= 599) { return "green"; }
    else { return "#000"; }
}
var colorNodes = function(nodelist){
    var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
    nodelist.forEach(function (n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0,3),10));
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        colorNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
    });
}

$('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
    colorNodes(tree.get_json());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know your code need to put which part?

Comment: I have tried to put in the <script>, but can't work

Comment: I've fixed the code now. The tree ID's were incorrect. You should add it after initializing the tree.

Comment: Sorry. Can you check for me this code https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/n6deaocv/3/ which part I get the wrong? Because the result still haven't changed it.

Comment: Your php code will not work on jsFiddle. I have a working demo with your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3oyxq4Lt/). I've removed the php sections & placed your sample json in the textarea.